# Why 'self' needed for patch and assert in Python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, patch, assert

I usually use:

```
def create_patch(self, name, value = None):
    patcher = patch(name)
    mock = patcher.start()
    mock.return_value = value
    self.addCleanup(patcher.stop)
    return mock

def assertXmlEqual(self, a, b):
    with open(a, 'r') as f:
        axml = f.read()
    with open(b, 'r') as f:
        bxml = f.read()
    self.assertEqual(loads(dumps((parse(axml)))), loads(dumps((parse(bxml)))))
```

and in testcases:

```
mockobj = self.create_patch('mymodule.myclass.mymethod', 'myvalue')

self.assertXmlEqual('expect.xml', 'result.xml')
```

But for every unit test class, I have to copy it.

Is there any way to make these more testcase-independent, more like a lib, like `Moq` and `Assert` in .net and `mock` and `expect` in Ruby?

Here is how they behave. See? They are independent of testcases.

`Moq` and `Assert`:

```
var obj = new Moq.Mock<MyPackage.MyClass>() { CallBase = true };
obj.Setup(p => p.MyMethod(Moq.It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(false);

Assert.AreEqual(expect, result)
```

`allow` and `expect`:

```
obj = double
allow(obj).to receive(:my_method).and_return('myvalue')

expect(result).to eq(expect)
expect(obj).to have_received(:my_method).exactly(3).times
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a base test case and then have all of your other test cases inherit from *that* instead of `unittest.TestCase`:

```
class MyBaseTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def create_patch(self, name, value = None):
        patcher = patch(name)
        mock = patcher.start()
        mock.return_value = value
        self.addCleanup(patcher.stop)
        return mock

    def assertXmlEqual(self, a, b):
        with open(a, 'r') as f:
            axml = f.read()
        with open(b, 'r') as f:
            bxml = f.read()
        self.assertEqual(loads(dumps((parse(axml)))), loads(dumps((parse(bxml)))))


class MyTestCaseThatTestsSomething(MyBaseTestCase):
    def test_something(self):
        self.patch('something.dependency', 'Hello World')
        result_xml = something()
        self.assertXmlEqual(result_xml, expected_xml)
```

Comment: Good try with inheritance. Is there another more elegant way like ```Moq``` and ```Assert``` in .net and ```mock``` and ```expect``` in Ruby?

Comment: @Mike -- As far as I'm aware, this is _the_ way to accomplish this with python's `unittest`.  I don't know how `Moq` and `Assert` work in .net, nor do I know how `mock` and `expect` work in ruby.  What about the previously mentioned frameworks makes them "more elegant"?  What behavior are you looking for exactly?  It's possible that there is a different unit test framework for python that would be closer to what you're looking for.

Comment: I added more details :)